# Examples of Superselection

Tags: quantum-mechanics, observables, quantum-states

1. What are some real physical examples of two states $|\psi\rangle$ and $|\phi\rangle$ satisfying $\langle\psi|A|\phi \rangle = 0$ for any observable $A$? Are there any such cases where $|\psi\rangle$ and $|\phi\rangle$ are
   two distinct eigenstates of a single observable $O$, in which case
   at least $\langle \psi|O|\phi\rangle = 0 $ would trivially hold?
2. Also, if $\langle\psi|A|\phi \rangle = 0$ for any observable $A$, and $|\psi\rangle$ and $|\phi\rangle$ are
   two eigenstates of an observable, does this mean that the Hermitian operator $(|\psi\rangle+ |\phi\rangle)(\langle\phi| + \langle\psi|)$ cannot be an observable due to the superselection rule?

Answer (score 4):

Consider a quantum system that admits electric charge. The superselection rule of electric charge requires that all observables must commute with the (spectral measure of the) charge observable. Now consider two eigenstates $\psi$, $\psi'$ of the charge observable, a selfadjoint operator $Q$ with point spectrum. Assume that the eigenvalues are distinct:  $Q\psi = q\psi$ and $Q\psi'= q'\psi'$ where $q\neq q'$. As a consequence of the commutativity requirement above, every observable $A$ cannot change the eigenvalue of these vectors. For instance $$QA\psi = AQ\psi= qA\psi.$$ Therefore $A\psi$ and $\psi'$ are orthogonal because eigenvectors of different eigenvalues are orthogonal.

I do not understand well the physical meaning of your second question.

However, if you reinforce the hypotheses, then the statement is true. If $\psi$ and $\phi$ are eigenvectors with different eigenvalues, $\lambda\neq \mu$ respectively, of a bounded observable $Q$ *in the center of the (von Neumann) algebra of observables*, then the selfadjoint operator
$$A := |\psi +\phi\rangle \langle \psi+\phi|$$
is not an observable. (Notice that your other hypothesis on the two vectors is automatically true in this case.)

Here is the proof.

Suppose that $A$ stays in the algebra of the observables. Then it must commute with $Q$:
$$QA=AQ.$$
Using the above expression of $A$, we easily get
$$\lambda (|\psi\rangle\langle \phi|- |\phi\rangle\langle \psi|)=\mu (|\psi\rangle\langle \phi|- |\phi\rangle\langle \psi|).$$
Since the eigenvectors are orthogonal (they having different eigenvalues)  and do not vanish, applying $\langle\psi| \cdot|\phi\rangle$ on both sides, we have a contradiction $\lambda=\mu$.